# Cannot find certain import on Java

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, resolve

I am working with an example of a simple JSF and I am using NetBeans. With NetBeans, I can't seem to resolve these imports

```
import javax.inject.Named; 

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
```

but when I go to Eclipse to check, there seems to be no problem. They are found by the Java class created in Eclipse. I was wondering: what are the things that I need to import or configure with NetBeans so that I won't have this problem of my class not seeing packages?

Also, I just updated everything before posting this question

Comment: And you have installed the Java Web plugin in NetBeans?

Comment: You need CDI enabled (contexts dependency inject JSR-299), sorry, I'm an eclipse user so don't know how to specify it in netbeans.  (Sorry, originally added this as an answer by mistake, deleted that as it's not)

Comment: hey folks, sorry for the trouble. but they seem to work now after choosing the glassfish as the server. before, I chose tomcat. thanks for the answers :D

Comment: @simon Please add your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted so others will know there is a solution.

Comment: @JonathanSpooner ok jonathan, thanks for informing me. but i might have to accept the answer tomorrow just like what the pop up box said :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they seem to work now after choosing the glassfish as the server. before, I chose tomcat which i guess don't have the imports that i want to use

Answer (score 8):

In the project view expand Libraries and add 'Java EE 6 API Library' this will add the required packages. The required file is javaee-api-6.0.jar.

Alternativly as maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out that the correct reference library is added in netbeans in your applications build path.

Comment: I believe that simon is aware that this is the issue. He is asking "what are the things that I need to import"

Comment: hi it is ok now. i chose glassfish as the server to replace tomcat. thnaks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

A solution to continue developing with Tomcat are change the imports and annotations to:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="namebean")
@SessionScoped
```

It's an old question but someone can have the same problem ...

Answer (score 0):

`@ManagedBean` is intended for use with legacy application servers and standalone servlet runners.

`@Named` is the best choice with a Java EE 6 compliant application server.

If you are using Maven, then you could use the above mentioned dependency in your pom file. Else you could just download the javaee 6 api jar file (javaee-api-6.0.jar) and add it to your class path. That should get it working.
It is readily available online. Here is one of those links: 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/javaee-api/javaee-api-6.0.jar.zip